# How to write a Laravel query to group duplicate records

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

This is my current query getting data from tables `corporations`, `jobs`, `corp_networks` and `candidates`.

```
$sqlCandSkills = DB::table('corporations')
    ->join('jobs', 'corporations.corp_id', '=', 'jobs.corp_id')
    ->join('corp_logos', 'corp_logos.corp_id', '=', 'corporations.corp_id')
    ->join('candidates', 'corporations.corp_id', '=', 'candidates.corp_id')
    ->join('corp_networks', 'corporations.corp_id', '=', 'corp_networks.participation_corp_id')
    ->where([
        'corp_networks.owning_corp_id' => $this->corp->corp_id,
        'corp_networks.status' => "Accepted"
    ])
    ->orwhere([
        'corporations.corp_id' => $this->corp->corp_id
    ])
    ->where('candidates.is_available', '=', 0)->get();
```

I need to add a validation query into this because I'm getting multiple rows of same data from above query.

```
for($i=0 ; $i<sizeof($skillsArray); $i++){
    $value= $skillsArray[$i];

    echo($value);

    $jobDetails = DB::select(
        'SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_technical_requirements LIKE "%'.$value.'%" AND job_status = 1 INNER JOIN '
    );
}
```

Above query gives all data but I also need to perform above checks.
I'm doing this second query to compare array of values to a csv values in column.
Now I need to achieve all this into a single result.
I need ways to do it either in sql query or laravel query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupBy

```
    $sqlCandSkills = DB::table('corporations')
    ->distinct()
    ->join('candidates', 'corporations.corp_id', '=', 'candidates.corp_id')
    ->join('corp_networks', 'corporations.corp_id', '=', 'corp_networks.participation_corp_id')
    ->where([
        'corp_networks.owning_corp_id' => $this->corp->corp_id,
        'corp_networks.status' => "Accepted"
    ])
    ->orwhere([
        'corporations.corp_id' => $this->corp->corp_id
    ])
    ->where('candidates.is_available', '=', 0)
    ->groupBy(array(
        'corporations.corp_id',
        'corp_networks.participation_corp_id',
        'corp_networks.owning_corp_id'
        ))
    ->get('corporations.corp_id');
```